# How to get all columns that are used from various tables?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Lets say I have 10 tables (`Table1` - `Table10`) and 10 columns in each table (lets say `Column1` - `Column10`) - same column names across tables. I wanna find all columns in all tables that are `not NULL` for at least one row in that table and insert them into temp table for example `@usedColumns` that will be used later in the stored procedure.

What would be the fastest and most efficient way to do it assuming that you have millions of records in any or all of these tables? Current implementation uses `UNPIVOT`, but I'm trying to redesign that stored procedure since it's acting really slow. Or is `UNPIVOT` really the most efficient way?

One way I was thinking is to just check for `if exists`, but can't figure out how to put this into an efficient loop:

```
if exists (select top 1 1
    from Table1
    where Column1 is not null)
    insert into @usedColumns ( table_name, column_name )
    values                   ( 'Table1',   'Column1'   );

if exists (select top 1 1
    from Table1
    where Column2 is not null)
    insert into @usedColumns ( table_name, column_name )
    values                   ( 'Table1',   'Column2'   );
...
```

The DB in question is SQL Server, but I'm guessing the solution would work in MySQL and others too.

Comment: The only way I know of doing it in MySQL is using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` and PREPARE-ing constructed queryies.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this. Sorry i was typing from my phone.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @count int = 1
declare @tablename nvarchar(20)

while @count < 11
begin    
    select @tablename = concat('table', @count)    
    select @sql = concat('select * from '
                    , @tablename
                    , ' where column1 is not null...')    
    --select @sql
    exec sp_sqlexec @sql    
    select @count = @count + 1    
end
```